# Python regular expressions: changing conditional operators

Tags: python, regex, grouping, substitution, conditional-operator

In Python, I am trying to use a regular expression that replaces all less than (<) and less than and equal to (<=) expressions with the equivalent greater than (>) or greater than or equal to equivalent. For instance, "a < b" would be replaced with "b > a". I believe my code for the regular expression is correct (shown below), but I don't know how to do the substitution part of the code. Since the regular expression is grouped, I have to use backreferences in order to access the parts of the expression I want to switch.

```
c = re.compile(r"\b(\w+)\s*"
           r"((<)|(>)|(<=)|(>=))"
           r"\s*(\w+)\b")
subStr = r"\7 #WHAT GOES HERE \1"
```

I can use \7 to get the "word" on the right side of the conditional operator and \1 to get the one of the left side. How do I flip the operator sign though??

To actually use substitution, I am using something in this format:

```
print(c.sub(subStr, "a < b"))
```

Also, I know I don't have to use a regular expression here, but I am trying to make it work with one.

Comment: Didnt `str.replace` help you?

Comment: You should match `(<|>)(=?)` and replace with `>\1`.

Comment: Oh good idea on the matching. But replace what with >\1?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function in [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to do something like this:

```
import re

txt='''\
a<b
a<=b'''

di={'<':'>', '<=':'>='}                       # expand as needed
print re.sub(r'\b(\w+\s*)(<|<=)(\s*\w+)',     # use your regex if wanted
           lambda m: m.group(3)+di[m.group(2)]+m.group(1), txt)
```

Prints:

```
b>a
b>=a
```